# Laravel 5 returns 403

Tags: php, laravel-5

My laravel 5 app returns http status `code 403` instead of `200` - this is strange becouse app doesen't do anything:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return 'welcome';
} );
```

The same thing happens when I launch default Laravel welcome View:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return View('welcome');
} );
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

**UPDATE:**
It happens only if route is defined as '/' - when the same code is launched for example via `/test` route site returns normal `200` response.

Comment: Fan of easiest solutions here! Just redirect `/` to something else, problem solved.

Comment: Do you have APP_DEBUG set to true? What does your stack trace look like? I just installed a fresh version of Laravel, copied and pasted your snippet into my routes file, and everything is working fine, as expected.

Comment: either a dependency issue or something you changed in your code. Could you maby try recreate the issue by cloning a new instance of laravel and see if you can recreate it. Also try add APP_DEBUG and see if you get any more hints.